# Alternatives to acoustic foam

Tags: acoustics, studio

I get health reactions from acoustic foam. I tried different brands. It's unfortunate.

Still, i would like to treat the acoustics in my little home studio as good as possible. What could i use as alternatives?

My thoughts were sheepwool pelts/skins, you know, those things you can sit on. Another idea were wool carpets.

Perhaps someone has more or better suggestions.

Also, if i get carpets, maybe someone could tell me which type would be the best to dry out the sound.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your objective? To isolate your studio from the rest of the house, or to reduce echo, or to make the room sound livelier? Without knowing what you want to do, our suggestions may take you in the opposite directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider building some Rockwool/Glasswool panels covered with acoustic cloth on it, in order to avoid health issues. (use proper protection if you decide to build these by yourself). In case you have already considered this, I've seen some people building panels using old towels. Here's a video showing the results.

Its impressive how effective they are. Obviously they will be more effective in higher frequencies than lower, it should depend on the thickness of the panel you build.

Answer (score 0):

According to my youtube research, foams and panels may mildly affect the acoustics within the room (which is useful for recording) but does nothing to help with acoustic leakage to the outside.

The best way to isolate a room is a double layer of drywall or other hard walling material, well sealed. Then, within that should be a layer of insulation. Then, there should be a pocket of dead air. Then more insulation, and a double layer of walling on the other side.

This kind of setup gives vibratory motions literally no path to the outside. Except the windows and the door.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen rehearsal rooms and studios use 36-piece egg cartons like these on the walls floor to ceiling: https://www.critter-cages.com/images/gq00202.jpg.

Comment: My guess is that you have seen something quite different, and believed it to be egg cartons. Studios often use "acoustic foam" (do a google search) which might look look like egg cartons from a distance.

Comment: @ghellquist : they were effectively egg cartons. I know the acoustic foam you're talking about, but that wasn't it. The acoustic results of using egg cartons are obviously not as good as the "real deal", but they do provide some dampening.